Custom rewrite rules for CPT
I have a "place" CPT with URLS like /places/name
I would like to add a custom page for every CPT with the format function
custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule("^place/([^/]+)/customlandingpage/?",'index.php?post_type=place&place=$matches[1]&landingpage=1','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 1, 0);

The issue: If I visit URL like /place/name/customlandingpage I'm redirected to /places/name instead of seing the custom page.
I register my CPT like this: (simplified)
function cpt_place() {
    $args = array(
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'custom-fields','thumbnail', 'page-attributes' ),
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'rewrite'               => array(
            'with_front'    => false,
            'pages'         => false,
            'ep_mask'       => EP_ALL,
            'slug'          => 'places',
        ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'place', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_place', 10 );

I also use:
function custom_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'place';
    $vars[] = 'landingpage';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_query_vars');

function load_custom_template($template) {
    if (get_query_var('place') && get_query_var('landingpage')) {
        $new_template = locate_template(array('landingpages.php'));
        if (!empty($new_template)) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'load_custom_template', 99);

function populate_landing_page_template() {
    global $wp_query;

    $place_slug = $wp_query->get('place');
    $landing_page = $wp_query->get('landingpage');
}
add_action('elementor_pro/posts/query', 'populate_landing_page_template');

A (simplified) var_dump of global $wp_rewrite; gives me this for extra_rules_top:
"^place/([^/]+)/customlandingpage/?" => "index.php?post_type=place&place=$matches[1]&landingpage=1"
"places/?$" => "index.php?post_type=place"

What am I missing ?
